# how to use input type date in my angular4 app? current browser is mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, typescript

I'm currently working in Angular4 app. And I used input type date, it is working in chrome, but not working in mozilla.
How to solve this issue? I thought I can use jQueryUi datepicker, but it makes some issues as well.

Any ideas about this?

Comment: What do you mean 'isn't working'? `input="date"` is an HTML5 item, so it's most likely your firefox is severely outdated. Jquery UI has browser support for all the latest browsers.

Comment: The MDN [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) say so too. Check 'Browser compatibility' section on that link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issues using jQuery Ui datepicker.
  Like this.

```js
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
...
declare var $: any;

export class MyClass implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('datepicker1') el1: ElementRef;
  
  ...
    ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(this.el1.nativeElement).datepicker();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Angular Material Datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) its worked for me both on chrome and firefox with no issues. [image: Datepicker]